# blackberry - bring field to the front within NegativeMarginVerticalFieldManager

Tags: java, user-interface, blackberry

I'm stuck with a problem of bringing a field to the front as it's drawing, has anyone countered a problem like this before?

In plain words, the problem is that I'm using `NegativeMarginVerticalFieldManager` from the [Advanced UI](https://github.com/blackberry/Samples-for-Java/tree/master/Advanced%20UI) samples, I use it to display a highlighted text under each panel button, the text should go in front of the content under the panel, but now it's going in the back of it.

[image]

So, does any one know how to make it appear in the front?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of paint is different. Could you override paint in your fields and check order of painting?

Unfortunately there z-order is connected to order how fields were added to manager and I don't know how to change it.

What you could do - override paint in manager and call paint for children in your needed order:

```
public class MyManager extends NegativeMarginVerticalFieldManager {
    protected void paint(Graphics g) {
        for (int i = 1; i < getFieldCount(); i++) {
            paintChild(getField(i), g);
        }

        if (getFieldCount() > 0)
           paintChild(getField(0), g);
    }
}
```

This is hack - I'm painting first field after all other.

Comment: Override paint method of the manager? I usually override `sublayout` method to customize children layout, I checked the `sublayout` method in `NegativeMarginVerticalFieldManager` and changed the order in which the `layoutChild` method is called, but nothing changed, can you please provide a piece of code or smthn? thanks.

Comment: Updated answer, please review